# Computing the derivative of a system of equations in the neighborhood of a point using implicit differentiation and the implicit function theorem

Tags: real-analysis, systems-of-equations, implicit-function-theorem

I'm solving the following problem on an old exam in real analysis. Thus, only such methods may be used.

> The system
>       \begin{align*}
>   \begin{cases}
>    \sin(x+y)+\sin(y+z)+z=0 \\
>    \cos(x+y)+\cos(y+z)+y-2=0
>   \end{cases}
>  \end{align*}
>       is satisfied at the point $(0,0,0)$. Show that $(x,y)$ can be solved in a neighborhood of $(0,0)$ as a function of $z$ for $z$ near 0. Calling the function $f(z)$, calculate explicitly $f'(0)$.

I solved a similar problem in a similar way, but am a bit confused as how to deal with the differences here. The problem was the following.

> The system
>       \begin{align*}
>  \begin{cases}
>   x+y+z=6 \\
>   x^2+y^2+z^2=14
>  \end{cases}
>  \end{align*}
>       is satisfied at the point $(1,2,3)$. Show that $x$ and $y$ can be solved in a neighborhood of $(1,2,3)$ as a function of $z$. Calculate also $x'(3)$ and $y'(3)$, where $x$ and $y$ are regarded as functions of $z$.

My solution was the following.

> Denote $F(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2-14$ and $G(x,y,z)=x+y+z-6$. The point $(1,2,3)$ is a solution to this system of equations. Let $H=(F,G)$. If
>       \begin{align*}
>   \frac{\partial(F,G)}{\partial(x,y)}=
>   \begin{vmatrix}
>    \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y} \\
>    \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y}
>   \end{vmatrix}
>   =
>   \begin{vmatrix}
>    \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} \\
>    \frac{\partial G}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial G}{\partial y}
>   \end{vmatrix}
>   =
>   \begin{vmatrix}
>    2x & 2y \\
>    1 & 1
>   \end{vmatrix}
>   =2x-2y\neq0
>  \end{align*}
>       for $(x,y,z)=(1,2,3)$. The Implicit Function Theorem now implies that there are $C^1$ functions $x(z)$ and $y(z)$ defined on the ball $B_r(1,2,3)$ that satisfy the above system with $x(z)=2$ and $y(z)=3$.
>
> Now
>       \begin{align*}
>   x+y+z&=6 \\
>   x^2+y^2+z^2&=14  
>  \end{align*}
>       becomes
>       \begin{align*}
>   x'+y'+1&=0 \\
>   2xx'+2yy'+2z&=0
>  \end{align*}
>       becomes
>       \begin{align*}
>   x'+y'+1&=0 \\
>   2x'+4y'+6&=0
>  \end{align*}
>       since $(x,y,z)=(1,2,3)$. Now
>       \begin{align*}
>   x'&=-y'-1 \\
>   y'&=-x'-1
>  \end{align*}
>       are used to obtain
>       \begin{align*}
>   2x'+4y'+6&=2x'+4(-x'-1)+6=2x'-4x'-4+6=-2x'+2=0\Leftrightarrow x'=1 \\
>   2x'+4y'+6&=2(-y'-1)+4y'+6=-2y'-2+4y'+6=2y'+4=0\Leftrightarrow y'=-2.
>  \end{align*}

I know how to solve for a functions $x(z)$ and $y(z)$, but not for $f(z)$. This makes it hard for me to compute the derivative there implicitly as well.

Comment: I'm stuck with finding $f(z)$. That's kind of the problem. I'm even stuck with showing that the determinant is nonzero.

Comment: Personally, these are basically the same. You do not need to explicitly write down the expression of $f \colon z \mapsto (x(z), y(z))$.

Comment: Okay. I don't see it. Do could you write it down as an answer and I'll have a look at it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo.

**Solution**. $\blacktriangleleft$ Denote the LHS of two equations respectively by $F(x,y,z), G(x,y,z)$. Then 
\begin{align*}
& \partial_x F = \cos(x+y), & &\partial_y F = \cos(x+y) + \cos(y+z),& \\
&\partial_x G = -\sin(x+y),& &\partial_y G = -\sin(x+y) - \sin(y+z) + 1,&
\end{align*}
where each of these partial derivatives is continuous around $(0,0,0)$. Since
$$
\det \left.\left( \frac {\partial(F,G)} {\partial (x,y)}\right)\right|_{(0,0,0)} = 
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1
\end{vmatrix}
= 1 \neq 0,
$$
the implicit function theorem could be applied to $F = 0, G= 0$, i.e. around $(0,0,0)$ there exists $\mathcal C^1$ functions $x(z), y(z)$ s.t. $F(x(z), y(z),z) = G(x(z), y(z), z) = 0 $ and $x(0) = y(0) = 0$.

Now calculate the derivatives. Take the derivative w.r.t. $z$ in the given system of equation:
$$
\begin{cases}
\cos(x+y) (x’ + y’) + \cos(y + z) (y’ + 1) +1 = 0 \\
-\sin(x+y)(x’+y’) - \sin(y+z) (y’ + 1) + y’ = 0
\end{cases},
$$
and let $z = 0$ we have 
$$
\begin{cases}
x’(0) + 2y’(0) + 1 = 0\\
y’(0) = 0
\end{cases},
$$
then $x’(0) = -1, y’(0) = 0$, hence $f’(0) = [-1\;0]^{\mathsf T}$ [maybe you do not need to take the transpose, depend on your notation system]. $\blacktriangleright$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\cos(x+y)(x'+y')+\cos(y+z)(y'+1)+1=0$ since the derivative of $z$ wrt $z$ is 1? Otherwise, your solution was great. Thanks! It cleared some things up for me.

Comment: @OskarTegby Yeah, thanks, I missed that term.